# Silverlight custom navigation window

Tags: silverlight, navigation

I am developing a Silverlight  MVVM app. I have a window with a frame. I have 3 pages, the first for data input, the second for editing the data, and the third for the user to review data and commit changes.
I added 2 buttons, "previous" and "forward", so that the user can navigate. 
The "previous"button is going to use the NavigationService.GoBack() method, but I cant figure out how the "next" button is going to know what the next page is.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a navigation application. You'd be much better off with a MVVM framework like Caliburn.Micro and use a shell view to display the content instead of a frame.